# Scikit-fuzzy getting error raise ValueError("Unexpected input: " + key)

Tags: python, data-science

My code - on scikit-fuzzy lib 
- 2  inputs - one temperature in room, another desired temperature. Output - temperature sugested in boiler furnace. Everything in °C.

```
pastebin.com/Vz3cMXUk
```

I really can't dont know how to resolve this, any ideas? Please

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "skifu.py", line 54, in <module>
    heating.input['temptarget']=int(30)
  File "/home/cant_roar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skfuzzy/control/controlsystem.py", line 168, in __setitem__
    raise ValueError("Unexpected input: " + key)
ValueError: Unexpected input: temptarget
/home/cant_roar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py:197: Warning: Source ID 8 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._idle_draw_id)
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO! I don't know much about `skfuzzy`, but since it's a `ValueError`, I would spend some time checking the kinds of inputs `heating` is allowed to take and what you're trying to give it (an `int`) vs. what you actually are giving it. The error looks like it's actually trying to process the string `temptarget` and not the `int` you want. Are there problems in assignment, grouping (parens/brackets), etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the line where you initialised the Antecedents. You must be making a mistake in variable name. Make sure that you enter the name in same manner as your entered before.